# Simple Javascript decoding

Tags: javascript, unicode, bots

So I know what escape hex characters are, like

```
"\x72\x75\x6E\x43\x6C\x69\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x6F\x74\x73"
```

but what do the numbers and letters mean in this array:

```
var E = ["\x72\x75\x6E\x43\x6C\x69\x65\x6E\x74\x42\x6F\x74\x73", U3, G3, "\x23\x74\x6F\x6B\x65\x6E", F3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to U3, G3, and F3? Those look to be variables that are probably declared somewhere else in the code.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at a segment of someone's code, I'm really new to javascript. I can't believe I never thought of those as variables. Thanks!